# Is it true that if $E[X]>0$ then $P(X>0)\ge E[X^2]/(E[X])^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation

If $E[X]>0$ then does $P(X>0)\ge \frac{E[X^2]}{(E[X])^2}$?

Background: I've taken an introductory course in probability.

Comment: No, (almost) never. By Jensen's inequality, $E[X^2]/(E[X])^2\ge1$.

Comment: Well, that's false but there is a related claim that is true.  By Markov's inequality $P(X \leq 0) \leq P(|X-E[X]|\geq E[X]) \leq \frac{E[(X-E[X])^2]}{E[X]^2} = \frac{E[X^2]}{E[X]^2}-1$, and by taking complements you get that $$P(X>0) \geq 2- \frac{E[X^2]}{E[X]^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X=1$ with probability .6 and $X=-1$ with probability .4.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. It's quite close to something that is true though. If you suppose that $X \ge 0$, then we do in fact have
$$P(X > 0) \ge \frac{(E(X))^2}{E(X^2)}.$$
This is called the "[second moment method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_method)", and it follows straightforwardly from Cauchy-Schwarz. (The RHS is the reciprocal of what you've got.)

However, this doesn't hold for general $X$ with $E(X) > 0$. As a counter-example, take $X_\epsilon \sim N(\epsilon,1)$. Then $E(X_\epsilon) = \epsilon$ and $E(X_\epsilon^2) = 1 + \epsilon^2$. Consider $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$. Then $E(|X_\epsilon|) \simeq E(|X_0|) = 1$ (you can work this out by hand without much difficulty, I leave that as an exercise). Then the RHS is approximately $1$, but the LHS is approximately $1/2$.

Comment: Whoops, thank you for the typo corrections @Did.